# Pasting tables from Microsoft Word into Rich Text fields

Tags: redactor, richtext, wysiwyg

How do you paste a table created in Microsoft Word into a Rich Text field in Craft?

Comment: The Rich Text field type that comes in Craft CMS.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment. Craft 2.5 uses the updated Redactor II WYSIWYG editor, which dropped this from it's features. All pasted text is stripped to plain text.

Perhaps someone can suggest an alternative method that we can set up to make this easy for content editors.

Comment: FWIW we have just heard from Imperavi that they are loosening up their stance on this in a future update.